# Symbol for Set of Vector Fields?

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a commonly used symbol that denotes a set of vector fields. It looks like an `\st{$\chi$}` (using the `soul` package, that is, `\usepackage{soul}`, but doesn't look so artificial.

Can someone help me? Also, this is my first posting on this SE so I'm not entirely sure of how to format things.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for searching for the command of a symbol whose shape you know.

Comment: I tried Detexify but it didn't help!

Comment: [I found it using Detexify](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n1vP8.png) - you sometimes have to click on "Select from the complete list" and scroll through the items. In my opinion, this is a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: Also used is $\Gamma (TM)$ as in "set of all smooth sections of the tangent space".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The usual symbol for the set of vector fields is `\mathfrak{X}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\( \mathfrak{X}(M) \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!